# vectorized approach to change 1 dimensional boolean array to 2-dimensional, python 3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, boolean, vectorization

I have a vector of boolean with dimension `1 * n`, suppose `n = 6`.

```
vec = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

I want to change it to a `n * 2` matrix. For each element in `vec`, if it is `1`, then in the matrix the corresponding row should be `[1, 0]`; if it is `0`, then the corresponding row should be `[0, 1]`. So the resulting matrix should be

```
matr = [[1, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [1, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [1, 0]]
```

To convert the vector to matrix, I need an elegant vectorized approach (avoiding `for-loops`), since in real case `n` would be much larger than `6`.
The reason for this conversion is for machine learning classification purppose. The `vec` refers to `binary classification`, and the matr will be used for `categorical classification`. Maybe this information can make my question more specific.

I use Python 3, numpy/scipy, sklearn.

Can anyone help me with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `vec` is a `numpy.array`:

```
vec = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

You can then stack it column wise with itself bitwise XOR'd to flip the values from 0->1 and 1->0, eg:

```
out = np.stack((vec, vec ^ 1), axis=1)
```

Gives you:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

Thanks to [Warren Weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser) for suggesting a faster broadcasting approach in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45913064/vectorized-approach-to-change-1-dimensional-boolean-array-to-2-dimensional-pyth/45913566?noredirect=1#comment78786072_45913566):

```
vec[:,None] ^ [0, 1]
```

Basic timings:

```
In [33]: %timeit np.stack((a, a ^ 1), axis=1)
15.6 µs ± 199 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [34]: %timeit a[:,None] ^ [0, 1]
7.4 µs ± 45.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: You could eliminate the need for `stack` with something like `vec[:,None] ^ [0, 1]`.

Comment: @Warren fantastic thinking... it's also from a simple timeit ~50% faster - did you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: @aura I'd go for Warren's approach. It's not as obvious what it's doing necessarily but it's a lot faster and produces your desired result as well.

Comment: @JonClements Feel free to add it to your answer if you want--it's just a broadcasting variation of your code (I didn't think of using XOR).

Comment: @Warren brilliant thanks. I've added your solution and some timings to show it's clearly faster.

Comment: Added timings for bigger dataset in my post for all methods proposed thus far, as OP seems to be working with such a dataset.

Comment: My broadcasting version is faster than the `stack` version only when `vec` isn't too long--it has less overhead.  For large `vec`, it is doing twice as many computations, one of which is pointless (vec ^ 0), so it loses.  So much for "fantastic" and "brilliant". :)

Comment: @Warren you're your own worst self-critic by the sounds of it. Just because it's not necessarily the *one true approach* - depending on requirements - it's of use :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach with array-indexing. Basically, we would use a `2D` array with two sub-arrays for `0` and `1` mapping from `vec`. For the indexing part, [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) is very efficient for such repeated indices. The implementation would look something like this -

```
mapping = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
out = np.take(mapping, vec, axis=0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [115]: vec = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])

In [116]: np.take(np.array([[0,1],[1,0]]), vec, axis=0)
Out[116]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

Runtime test on bigger dataset -

```
In [108]: vec = np.random.randint(0,2,(10000000))

# @Jon Clements's soln
In [109]: %timeit np.stack((vec, vec ^ 1), axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 50.2 ms per loop

# @Warren Weckesser's suggestion soln
In [110]: %timeit vec[:,None] ^ [0, 1]
10 loops, best of 3: 90 ms per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [111]: %timeit np.take(np.array([[0,1],[1,0]]), vec, axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 31 ms per loop
```

Comment: Okay... let's try that again... I get stack: 2.44ms, broadcast: 3.12ms and take: 1.06ms so - looks like a further improvement :)

Comment: @JonClements Good to get the confirming results, thanks!